# Define a enum-variabele after declaration

Tags: c++, enums

I'm learning enumerations. I have the following problem: I don't understand, why this works:

```
enum {fahrrad = 1, Auto = 2} einFahrzeug;
int main() {
    einFahrzeug = fahrrad;
```

but this doesn't:

```
enum {fahrrad = 1, Auto = 2} einFahrzeug;
einFahrzeug = fahrrad;

int main() { ...
```

I would be very happy about an answer

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `enum`s. You can't have executable code in global scope. Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign stuff to variables outside of a function. More simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int x;
x = 42;

int main()
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

This gives:

```
prog.cpp:4:1: error: ‘x’ does not name a type
 x = 42;
 ^
```

Try it with ideone.com: https://ideone.com/A1K06A